# mod_rewrite does not stop processing rules after [L] match?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ default/public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ default/public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ default/public/index.php?uri=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my .htaccess.
Whenever trying to access http://domain.com/css/css.css, i only get the contents of default/public/index.php.
If i comment out the line that redirects to default/public/index.php?uri=$1, i get the contents of default/public/css/css.css, so the rule does match, but the [L] is apparently not working, because it does'nt terminate processing rules.

Anyone had the same problem?
Is it some server config error? Any ideas of how to fix this?

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the [L] is apparently not working

No that's not right, `L` flag is indeed working. Purpose of `L` flag is not to exist out of `mod_rewrite` processing. `mod_rewrite` rules are run in a loop and `L` acts as `continue` in programming parallels.

To fix this you can do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ default/public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ default/public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ default/public/index.php?uri=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is internal variable set by Apache after first rewrite.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for, apparently Apache also passes the rewritten URL through these rules, so I had to add two more lines like this, and it solved the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ default/public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^default/public/css/(.*)$ default/public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ default/public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^default/public/js/(.*)$ default/public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ default/public/index.php?uri=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```